# Merging Mutliple Rows Back into one with separate field markers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

I have done a join which has (correctly) duplicated certain rows that have multiple matches. My data looks as follows (after the join)

```
Job_ID    ....[MULTIPLE COLUMNS HERE]....  final_sub_team
----------------------------------------------------------
001                                        TEAM1
001                                        TEAM2
002                                        TEAM1
003                                        TEAM4
```

I want to merge these rows in the following way

```
Job_ID    ....[MULTIPLE COLUMNS HERE]....  Team1    Team2    Team3    Team4
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
001                                        Yes      Yes      No       No
002                                        Yes      No       No       No
003                                        No       No      No       Yes
```

I have tried the following:

```
 select 
     job_id, 
     Team1 = (select case when final_sub_team = 'Team1' then 'Yes' else 'No' end),
     Team2 = (select case when final_sub_team = 'Team2' then 'Yes' else 'No' end),
     Team3 = (select case when final_sub_team = 'Team3' then 'Yes' else 'No' end),
     Team4 = (select case when final_sub_team = 'Team4' then 'Yes' else 'No' end)
 from 
     AllJobs
 group by 
     Job_id
```

But that returns the error:

> Column 'AllJobs.Final_Sub_Team' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

So I am looking for some assistance of the way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select job_id ,
       Team1 = max(case when final_sub_team = 'Team1' then 'Yes' else 'No' end),
       Team2 = max(case when final_sub_team = 'Team2' then 'Yes' else 'No' end),
       Team3 = max(case when final_sub_team = 'Team3' then 'Yes' else 'No' end),
       Team4 = max(case when final_sub_team = 'Team4' then 'Yes' else 'No' end)
 from AllJobs
 group by Job_id;
```

This works because `'Yes'` > `'No'`, because strings are compared alphabetically.  More typically, I would recommend using `1` for yes and `0` for no.

Comment: This appears to give the error "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."

Comment: @AndreR. . . . There should be no subqueries in the logic.  I fixed the query.